# Google Analytics shows Duplicate Conversions When Using "Required Step" Feature

Tags: url, google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking

I have two goals set up in my Analytics.
Both have the same Goal Url but have different steps and have different 1st step which is required.

So for example for goal 1 I have:

1. /product1/step1 - required
2. /product1/step2
3. /thank-you

For goal 2 I have:

1. /product2/step1 - required
2. /product2/step2
3. /thank-you

When somebody buy product1 I get both goal 1 and goal 2 conversions in my analytics saying both products have been bought.

I don't quite understand what is 1st required step then for if not to check when the goal originated (what product have been bought)?

If I'm wrong, how do I set it up so they don't convert as one goal but as two goals as it is intended to work?

I need to use one Goal Url (/thank-you) just because it is a page where I check the payment have been processed. It would be silly to duplicate the same page for different goals.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The "Required Step" check box is ONLY utilized when viewing your results through the funnel visualization report.

It has no effect in the other reports.

In your particular case, you'll need to either use the visualization report exclusively (not recommended).   Or figure out a way to implement a different landing page.

> From Google Analytics Help:
>
> The required first step applies only to the Funnel Visualization report. When you mark a >first step as required, the Funnel Visualization report only includes goal conversions that >pass through that required step. Other visits are just dropped from the report.
>
> If you see a conversion rate in other reports but a zero conversion rate in the Funnel >Visualization report, this indicates that the required step wasn't viewed during visits that >converted

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2976313

Hope this helps.